# dataclasss python reconstruct value

Tags: python

lets say i have this dataclass

```
@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class TestMetaData:
    edit_meta: MetaData

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class MetaData:
    list_meta: list[MetaDataList]

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class MetaDataList:
    name: str
    fields: list[MetaDataFields]

class MetaDataFields:
    label: str
    name: str
```

i have a processing method to add data into this dataclass

```
data_args = {
        'test': TestMetaData(
            edit_meta=MetaData(
                list_meta=[
                    some_process_method(
                        meta
                    )
                    for meta in meta_info['metafields']
                ]
            )
        )
    }
return data_args
```

now i have data_args and when i wanted to return to frontend as dictionary i can do something like this

```
return {
  **data_args
}
```

but my question is, if i wanted to process data_args again before returning to frontend, how can i access data_args? using data_args['edit_meta'] as loop also wont help me to access the data inside. for my information i would like to learn how to access the data if is already converted into dataclass json

Comment: Please indicate where `dataclass_json` comes from, as it's not part of the standard `dataclasses` module.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses-json/